# IEnumerable with yield return and VS Quickwatch crash

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ienumerable, yield-return

I have the following method that return an `IEnumerable`

```
public IEnumerable<ExternalFilter> GetExternalFilters()
{
    if (externalfilters == null)
        yield break;
    foreach (ExternalFilter filter in externalfilters)
        yield return filter;
}
```

If I look at GetExternalFilter in VS Quickwatch, when expanding the collection, the in-debug program immediately crashes and Quickwatch shows nothing.

The same thing on evalutating `Count()` of that collection, with Quickwatch message `Function evaluation was aborted.`

What I need to have this functionality to work?

Comment: Does the call to Count() work normally from your code? Or do you get some exception?

Comment: Sidenote: more efficient to return the enumerable than just foreaching over the enumerables and returning each one, and if it's null it's still a valid return, as you will be returning null, which is what yield break will do before any yield returns.

Comment: @ofstream I think yield break returns an empty enumerable if externalfilter is null, and not just `null`.

Comment: @ConradClark Then just `return externalfilter ?? Enumerable.Empty<ExternalFilter>();`

Comment: @alex It works normally if I print the `Count` to Console for example.

Comment: @ofstream I use `foreach` because the returned collection must be immutable, so I don't want to return the list itself. Also, `yield break` returns an `Empty<T>`, not `null`.

Comment: Does it show `Function evaluation was aborted.` immediately or after several seconds? that could be an expression evaluation timeout

Comment: Could be a threading issue. Are you by any chance using [ThreadStatic] attributes or some thread-id checking?

Comment: @alex No thread in this project. I suspect that I need some special syntax to get Count working...

Comment: @Teejay Right, just return do this: `return object.Equals(externalfilter, null) ? Enumerable.Empty<ExternalFilter> : externalfilter.Select(n => n);`

Comment: @ofstream You forgot some casts... Anyway, `Cannot return a value from an iterator. Use the yield return statement to return a value, or yield break to end the iteration.`. And yes, I definitely WANT an iterator.

Comment: No, that seems perfectly fine. (Except for me missing the () in Enumerable.Empty). But why would you want one?

Comment: @ofstream Ok, let's rework the question. How can I make `Count` via Quickwatch working for a custom IEnumerable?

Comment: what type is `externalfilter`? How is it declared/implemented?

Comment: It is a `List` of a custom interface `IDBFilter`

Comment: Have you added `System.Linq` in the usings of the class where you tried to evaluate `Count()` through Quick watch ? Does it work with the full qualified name : `System.Linq.Enumerable.Count(GetExternalFilters())` ?

Comment: Yes, I have `System.Linq` in usings and No, it doesn't work, event with the full name: `Function evaluation was aborted.` and the running program immediately closes.

Comment: If `Count()` works outside of Quick Watch then it is probably a Visual Studio bug. `Function evaluation was aborted` is usually displayed when function evaluation causes a time out. Are you sure there are no infinite loops in your code ? And just to be sure, is this normal that your are checking `externalfilter` is not null and then iterating through `externalfilterS` ?

Comment: @SimonV. Seems not an infinite loop because it shows that message immediately. And don't mind about `externalfilterS`, just a typo in my question: fixed!

Comment: And I agree it's probably a VS bug. But, just to be sure, I would be glad if someone could test a similar situation..

Comment: Teejay you should probably post your externalfilters and couple related classes (what is holding IDBFilter, ExternalFilter?) to be able to tell anything more

Comment: @NSGaga It's a simple `public class ExternalFilter : IDBFilter`. It holds some properties and methods to provide a filtering structure for DataGridViews

Answer (score 1):

Just a hunch: maybe your enumeration `externalfilter` can only be evaluated once? (E.g. because of the source of the data).

Which means that as soon as you try to use QuickWatch to re-evaluate the result of `GetExternalFilters` it will fail.

If `externalfilter` is not just an enumerable but something like a simple `List<T>` then your problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: No, that's not the case. My `externalfilter` is a simple list.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your parameter `externalfilters` is not thread safe.

Do you update your parameter from another thread?

If so, use `lock` to update list and reading from it.

Comment: No, there are not other threads that use that variable. In addition, please note that the problem is with VS debugger *Quickwatch*